# Are there 'stack' sites for Mac or Windows?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

There is Ubuntu and Unix/Linux site but is there special 'stack' site for Mac and Windows?

For context, the question I am looking to ask: I accidentally connected a Windows NTFS formatted HDD to a Mac. And the Mac (may be) quick-formatted it. I think that the information is there, but the FAT table is gone. How I can recover the information.

Comment: possibly superuser, depending on your question ... I think

Comment: and possibly http://apple.stackexchange.com/, depending on your question

Comment: http://superuser.com/ for both, http://apple.stackexchange.com/ for Mac specific stuff

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Super User](http://superuser.com) is our general software/hardware site. It handles Windows, Mac, as well as Unix and Linux.

[Ask Different](http://askdifferent.com) is our Apple site, in the same vein as Unix & Linux and Ask Ubuntu are for theirs. We do not have an explicit Windows site in the same fashion, mostly because it is generally covered by Super User still.

Comment: as a note for followers, "askdifferent" appears to be equal to http://apple.stackexchange.com/ these days.

Comment: I am a died in the wool linux developer However its really time we cut a Windows flavor of stackexchange so those folks can leverage the benefits the rest of us enjoy ... stuffing that traffic into supersuser muddys the water there

Comment: i don't understand how there is an apple stackexchange but not windows one when there is at least 2-3x more users of windows. and there is easily 10x more windows users than ubuntu.

Comment: It primarily boils down to, not enough people wanted to make one. The creation of sites was developed through community pushing prospects through Area 51. Enough people in Unix & Linux, Ubuntu, and Apple pushed together to create sites for their needs because they felt the need. Windows apparently never bound together for that and were satisfied just sitting on Super User.

Answer (score -1):

For Windows Phone, embedded Compact I recommend you using https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/ (I don't know about Windows on Snapdragon 835 and 850).

For Windows Home, Pro, S, Enterprise and Server, http://superuser.com/ is the way to go and the Microsoft forums of course.